# How to expand a floating point raster by one pixel

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, zonal-statistics

In ArcGIS 10.2.2, I have a floating point raster of oceanographic data that boarders a coastline. Due to the jagged edge of the coast, the raster edge only sometimes overlaps the coastline and leaves gaps of NoData in other places - land shown in grey, NoData cells shown in white.

[image: raster of oceanographic data leaving gaps]

I want to expand the raster all the way to the land polygon so I can infer oceanographic values for points on the coastline, and it is only one cell short. Since it is a floating point raster and not a categorical raster, the Expand zone function isn't appropriate (there are no zones). Is there an equivalent of Expand for a floating point raster?

Comment: I don't think any such method like Expand or Nibble will because you have a float and they all need ints. The missing values actually need to be *interpolated*, not copied. I would look at [Focal Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000qs000000) to get the needed values, and then replace those pixels in the original with the focal stats values using Con.

Comment: Can't do a complete answer on the mobile app.  Try something like `Con(IsNull(your_raster), FocalStatistics(your_raster), your_raster) ` in the raster calculator